# On mobile web, fit to screen height the div box

Tags: css

I am trying to make a scrollable div box, and it's height should be exact fit to screen's height(100%).

The problem is if there is a another div box on the top which is the fixed height, how do I make scrollable box to fit to the screen's height?

This is what I tried

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top">
    Fixed height 100px. No floating or layered box 
  </div>
  <div class="scrollBox">
    Fluid height to screen height 100%
    <br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br>
  </div>

</div>


html, body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
.wrap { height:100%; background:lightblue }
.top { height:100px; background:green}
.scrollBox {  width:80%; height:100%; margin:0 auto 0 auto; border:1px solid #000; overflow-y:auto; background:#eee; }
```

This is my demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/a5ktensk/77/

Please help

Comment: You can set it to `100vh` instead of 100%.

Comment: Use the `vh` unit, not percent. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/viewport-height-for-full-screen-div/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there `calc()` function will be handy, try following way:

```
.scrollBox {  
    width:80%; 
    height:calc(100% - 100px); /* Key Line */
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    overflow-y:auto; background:#eee; 
}
```

Comment: Also see here: http://jsfiddle.net/a5ktensk/85/

Comment: Thank you problem solved for you comment :)

Comment: @user1833620 jsfiddle with this answer still shows scrollbar to page. Then how this solved your problem? Just to know:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vh unit to achieve this.

So

```
.scrollBox {height: 100vh; }
```

vh means viewheight, so will be the current height shown, you can take a little away using the calc feature in CSS

```
.scrollBox {height: calc(100vh - 100px);
```

So that will be 100% of the hieght minus 100px for example if you want a fixed div at the top :)

http://jsfiddle.net/g7d2k59m/1/

Answer (score 1):

Apply `height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;` to `.wrap`.

> Height in vh will force page to use full height as per viewport.
>
> **Viewport Height (vh)** – A percentage of the full viewport height. 10vh
>   will resolve to 10% of the current viewport height.
>
> `Overflow:hidden` will stop `.wrap` from scrolling.

```css
html, body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
.wrap { height:100%; background:lightblue;height: 100vh;overflow: hidden; }
.top { height:100px; background:green}
.scrollBox {  width:80%; height:100%; margin:0 auto 0 auto; border:1px solid #000; overflow-y:auto; background:#eee; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top">
    Fixed height 100px. No floating or layered box 
  </div>
  <div class="scrollBox">
    Fluid height to screen height 100%
    <br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br><br>test<br>
  </div>

</div>
```

To know more about viewport units -

- https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

**Hope this helps :)**